# Firebase: How do I update value in array instead of adding new element in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase array that looks like this

```
categories:[{rating: 1, name: 'abc'}, {rating: 2, name: 'xyz'}]
```

How can I update the element with name 'abc' for example to make it something like this
{rating: 3, name: 'abc'}

I tried the below but it adds an element to the array as it considers it unique due to the different rating value.

```
var ref = _db.collection('reports').doc(user.uid);
const data = { categories: FieldValue.arrayUnion([{"name": 'abc', "rating": 3}]) } 
ref.set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the Array, modify it in your front-end and write it back to Firestore (i.e. update the document by passing the **entire** modified array).